# Is Windows (Services for Unix) NFS client "good enough"?

Tags: windows, nfs, netapp

For one of our platforms I have about 20 MSSQL 2K3 machines that need to drop their backups onto a few NetApp boxes (which then copy the backups to other data centres and does long-term storage).

These NetApps are currently only used by our Linux boxes and are NFS-only, I can buy the SMB licences if needed but need to consider a stable/trustworthy Windows NFS client.

Do you trust the built-in Windows SUA NFS client enough? Is there a 'better' third-party NFS client you'd recommend? Or would you just use SMB to mount the backup volumes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've been using it for years and it seems to work fine.